# Trying to get Drupal 7 UC drop down to show currently selected

Tags: variables, drop-down-menu, drupal-7, ubercart

I am trying to modify my code to get the dropdown to save to a variable(get) and to show that current value when the form opens [from a screen capture of the Ubercart checkout form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sk9EX.jpg)

The pic example is from the uc_checkout - but I cannot find the file that has this drop down code - it is not in ubercart/uc_cart/uc_checkout_pane.inc

Here is my code - the form is a nested array - the commented out line is WITHOUT the drop down

//      'uc_store_zone' => uc_textfield(t('Zone - State'), variable_get('uc_store_zone', 0), FALSE, NULL, 64),

```
$form['abc']['xyz'] = array(
  'uc_store_city' => uc_textfield(t('City'), variable_get('uc_store_city', NULL), FALSE, NULL, 128),  
  'uc_store_zone' => array(
    '#title' => t('State Name'),
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#description' => "Select the US State or US Territory.",
    '#options' => array('0' => t('- Select -'),
                      '1' => t('Alabama'),
                      '2' => t('Alaska'),
                      '3' => t('more . . . ').
                      '31' => t('Maryland'))
     ),
```

I cannot figure how to set the uc_texfield and variable get for the "select" array so it shows the currently selected value as the / a variable(get).  Everything I have tried throws an error.  The drop down however works fine and the form renders properly.

Can anyone tell me what I need to do ??